# android java how to protect/ secure my Hardcoded Password

Tags: java, android, react-native

i want to make CertPinning, sending request with clientcertificate. for that i need to put my password hardcoded to use it in the keystore init:

```
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, Password.toCharArray());
```

how can I protect it?

```
File pKeyFile;
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(OkHttpUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("assets/acptamancli.pfx"));
String Password= "MyPassword!";
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
// InputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream(caInput);
keyStore.load(caInput, Password.toCharArray());
caInput.close();
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, Password.toCharArray());
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());
SSLSocketFactory sockFact = context.getSocketFactory();
con.setSSLSocketFactory(sockFact);
/* Send the request */
OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(requestParams.getBytes("UTF-8"));
outputStream.close();
InputStream inputStream;

if(comparePKeys) {
    // Check for errors
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        inputStream = con.getInputStream();
    } else {
        inputStream = con.getErrorStream();
    }
} else{
    inputStream = con.getErrorStream();
}

// Process the response
InputStream is = inputStream;
int i;
BufferedReader reader;
String line = null;
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String result =  reader.readLine();
inputStream.close();
callback.invoke(null, result);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This way leads to insanity and is something that you *never* want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. Anything present in the distributed package can be accessed by someone who has it.

Note that you're mixing two separate concepts, certificate pinning and client certificates. Client certificates are very rarely used outside an internal corporate environment, and pinned public certificates don't need to be hidden.